# Increase speed to Xcode Builds (by terminal commands only)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, macos

There are more tips and tricks about how to decrease build timing.

Some of them are too old, other working only with simulator devices, other for example explain how to disable the code coverage support but always by make changes to the layout settings.

My purpose is to launch few effective terminal command lines or a good script (the last choice would be much better) so without changing Xcode layout settings, without adding libraries.., only by-terminal actions.

Now this is what I've found during years:

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode ShowBuildOperationDuration <YES/NO>
```

*(this is just only for debug, not effective results)*

```
defaults write com.apple.dt.XCode IDEIndexDisable <0/1>
```

*(this command disable indexing process)*

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks <1|2|4|8|16|..>
```

*(the number of threads Xcode will use to perform tasks defaults to the same number of cores your CPU has -> default value = CPU cores)*

```
defaults write com.apple.Xcode XCMaxNumberOfDistributedTasks <desired-number>
```

*(The user default XCMaxNumberOfDistributedTasks in the com.apple.Xcode domain controls how many concurrent compile jobs Xcode will send to the DNB system at once ; 25 by default)*

Do you know other type of useful efficient command lines to adding or a good script to launching (for example any code that check also CPU cores and correctly set `PBXNumberOfParallelBuildSubtasks` value) ?

I've found more arguments to set you can easily find here below doing:

```
defaults read com.apple.dt.XCode > xcodeprefs.json
```

Comment: do you really want to disable indexing though? I guess that's useful only for CI

Comment: Many people meet situations like "Xcode stuck on Indexing.." or "indexing endless..". This option could be useful in these particular cases when you want to solve a problem without awating too many time